# Menu Navigation effects similar to WashingtonPost.com

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I was wondering how to achieve the sliding motion effects upon pressing the menu buttons similar to the [washingtonpost.com](https://www.washingtonpost.com/) website. I'm talking about when you press the Sections (burger) menu button on that website, the main content along with the hidden menu slides to the right a bit farther than it should, and then it goes backward a bit to get to the place. Similarly, switching the off Nav menu, the whole page moves to the left using the same motion effect.

I have seen the similar motion elsewhere and believe it could be a standard effect of JQuery or a plugin, but just don't know which one.

Just need the effect name and/or reference to the code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1 year and 8 months later I have found the answer I was looking for.

```
cubic-bezier(0.175, 0.885, 0.320, 1.275);
```

All I wanted is this transition name (I don't know why my question was voted down 4 times).

Answer (score 0):

This **'easing'** is not a standard effect of jQuery (which only ships with two), or even jQuery UI (which adds on about 30 more). But perhaps you were thinking of **easeOutElastic**, which is demonstrated [here](http://easings.net/). It's likely that the Washington Post site is using a custom bezier curve in CSS, most likely with the help of a tool like [Ceaser](https://matthewlein.com/ceaser/).

Comment: I was just looking for the reference link and NOT for someone doing my work. Thanks for the answer.